# How do I use this JSON text in my app?

Tags: objective-c, json

I have the following JSON text as follows. I want to incorporate it into my app, and just be able to get parts of it assigned to variables to use. Simple, I know, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
[{"id":"1","category":"1","fact":"Worldwide, around 1.2 trillion eggs are produced for eating every year, which means that average person on Earth consumes 173 eggs a year."},{"id":"3","category":"2","fact":"How to tell if you're going to throw up? -Your mouth starts to fill with saliva which is there to protect your mouth and teeth from the stomach acid mixed with the vomit."},{"id":"2","category":"2","fact":"Bone cells are constantly renew so every ten years you have a new skeleton."}]
```

Comment: Do some searching on `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: Note that if you search Google for "objective-c json" you will get dozens of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your text looks an array. So try like this:-

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your json text is a NSString you need to convert it to NSData so:

```
    NSString* jsonText = @"[{"id":"1","category":"1","fact":"Worldwide, around 1.2 trillion eggs are produced for eating every year, which means that average person on Earth consumes 173 eggs a year."},{"id":"3","category":"2","fact":"How to tell if you're going to throw up? -Your mouth starts to fill with saliva which is there to protect your mouth and teeth from the stomach acid mixed with the vomit."},{"id":"2","category":"2","fact":"Bone cells are constantly renew so every ten years you have a new skeleton."}]";
    NSData* data = [jsonText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization 
    JSONObjectWithData:responseData
    options:kNilOptions 
    error:&error];
```

So now you can access to the elements like a dictionary.
Hope this helps you.